# If a cell is empty, exit print

Tags: vba, excel

My control button is printing a worksheet. I want the code to check if a specific cell has data, and if it doesn't, I want to have a message box pop up and exit the print function.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Control").Cells(C1)) Then
    MsgBox "You must have a Project Name to print!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Right now, it won't print the sheet at all, saying that there is an Application or Object defined error at

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Control").Cells(C1)) Then
```

I have 10 other cells that need to be checked individually so that a message specific to the missing data is prompted. How can I do this?

Comment: Put C1 in quotes "C1"

Comment: This produces an Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument at this line.

Comment: sorry, too quick.  Should be `If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Control").Range("C1"))`

Comment: That was it! Thanks! If you want to type that as an answer, I'll tick it up.

Comment: btw: for future info ... `.cells(1,"c")` or `.cells(1,3)` would also work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a string literal i.e. "C1" with double quotes. Also, use .Range("C1").Value instead of .Cells(C1).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Control").Range("C1").Value) Then
    MsgBox "You must have a Project Name to print!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: After adjusting the code to have the quotation marks around the cell, I now receive an error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument at the same line.

Comment: @TomStone What is the name of the worksheet that you are checking?

Comment: Worksheets("Control")

Comment: @TomStone Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control")` instead.